# SELECT MULTIPLE TEXT FROM A TEXT STRING USING REGEXP ORACLE

Tags: sql, regex, oracle11g

i have the following text string stored in an oracle 11g table

```
"MGK8M76HRT Confirmed. You have received Kshs 6,678.00 from Peter 0700123456 on 1/1/2018"
```

I would like to extract the following from the text using regexp

1. `6,678.00` - amount paid
2. `MGK8M76HRT` - unique payment transaction code (changes pattern everytime)
3. `0700123456` - phone number
4. `1/1/2018` -  payment date

I have tried multiple oracle regexp patterns to extract the texts without any success. Any assistance/ideas will be appreciated.

I tried:

```
CONFIRMATION_CODE_PATTERN = "[A-Z0-9]+ Confirmed."; 
PHONE_PATTERN = "07[\\d]{8}"; 
AMOUNT_PATTERN = "Ksh[,|.|\\d]+"; 
DATETIME_PATTERN = "d/M/yy hh:mm a";
```

Comment: What was the code you tried and that did not work?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew 

CONFIRMATION_CODE_PATTERN = "[A-Z0-9]+ Confirmed.";

PHONE_PATTERN = "07[\\d]{8}";

AMOUNT_PATTERN = "Ksh[,|.|\\d]+";

DATETIME_PATTERN = "d/M/yy hh:mm a";

Comment: You can't write `\d` inside a bracket expression in Oracle regex, use `0-9`. Please add the patterns to the question.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew

i think i must have confused this with regexp in java. Would you mind helping a brother out. :)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew
what of selecting the payer name? in this case "Peter" ?

Comment: If it is a word from `from`, use `regexp_substr('...', 'from\s+([[:alpha:]]+)', 1, 1, NULL, 1)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that inside bracket expressions, in Oracle regex, you cannot use regex escapes. `[\d]` does not match a digit, it matches a `\` or `d` chars. You should use `[0-9]` / `[[:digit:]]` instead. Next, you should use [capturing groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), `(...)`, to wrap those parts of the pattern that you want to exract.

You may use the following regular expressions:

```
select regexp_substr('MGK8M76HRT Confirmed. You have received Kshs 6,678.00 from Peter 0700123456 on 1/1/2018', 
                     'Kshs\s*(\d([,.0-9]*\d)?)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) as Paid from dual
\\
select regexp_substr('MGK8M76HRT Confirmed. You have received Kshs 6,678.00 from Peter 0700123456 on 1/1/2018', 
                     '(\D|^)(07\d{8})(\D|$)', 1, 1, NULL, 2) as Phone from dual
\\
select regexp_substr('MGK8M76HRT Confirmed. You have received Kshs 6,678.00 from Peter 0700123456 on 1/1/2018', 
                     '(\S+)\s+Confirmed\.', 1, 1, NULL, 1) as Code from dual
\\
select regexp_substr('MGK8M76HRT Confirmed. You have received Kshs 6,678.00 from Peter 0700123456 on 1/1/2018', 
                     '\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}') as TrDate from dual
```

Please organize this as per your requirements, it does not seem to be in the scope of the question.

Output:

[image]